# MongoDB Aggregate field between two dates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to aggregate complaints based on status between two dates.

Sample Data :

[image]

[In JSON format](https://pastebin.pl/view/f2f5312c)

Code :

```js
const result = await Complaint.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    createdAt: {
                        $gte: "2021-08-31T18:30:00.000Z",
                        $lt: "2021-09-30T18:29:59.999Z",
                    },
                },
            },
            { $group: { _id: "$status", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
        ]);
```

Expected result :

```js
[ { _id: 'progress', count: 1 }, { _id: 'raised', count: 4 } ]
```

but result is always coming as empty `[]`

Comment: please provide sample data

Comment: @mohammadNaimi added

Comment: give the data in JSON format, so we can test it. Your query looks ok if you convert strings to dates in both query and in database.Use `$dateFromString` in both query and database it will work i think.  (in query you can use ISODate also like the solution described bellow) but you need to have date object in database also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it

```
const result = await Complaint.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    createdAt: {
                        $gte: ISODate("2021-08-31T18:30:00.000Z"),
                        $lt: ISODate("2021-09-30T18:29:59.999Z"),
                    },
                },
            },
            { $group: { _id: "$status", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
        ]);
```

or

```
const result = await Complaint.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    createdAt: {
                        $gte: new Date("2021-08-31T18:30:00.000Z"),
                        $lt: new Date("2021-09-30T18:29:59.999Z"),
                    },
                },
            },
            { $group: { _id: "$status", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
        ]);
```

Comment: is there any result for $match query without group ?

Comment: This works actually. Stringified ISO dates worked with find query but not with aggregate. Once I started passing  JS Dates, it started working.